# Мене це не стосується

Tags: вживання-слів, керування-відмінками

Згідно з академічними словниками А.Кримського, О.Ізюмова, дієслово *стосуватися* вимагає прийменникової форми залежного слова *до кого, до чого*. Але вживаємо вислів "Мене це не стосується" (https://movnyk.com.ua/question/vzivannya-ce-do-mene-ne-stosuyetsya/). В  Російсько-українському народному словнику наводиться керування стосуватися кого? чого?

> •  иметь отношение к чему – стосуватися чого, ма́ти до чине́ння з чим, до чо́го, ма́ти щось до ко́го, ма́ти прито́ку до чо́го;
>
> Словник українсько-російський 1927р. (А. Ніковський) 
>   Стосува́тися, -су́юся (кого́, чого́, до чо́го) – 
>   1) касаться, относиться, трогать; 
>   2) применяться к ч.-н., иметь применение.

Чи можна вживати обидві форми як рівнозначні?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По правдї, за словником Агатангела Кримського допускається:

[стосуватися](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8F&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> 4) (*иметь отношение к чему*) торка́тися, торкну́тися, дотика́тися, діткну́тися, стосува́тися, ти́читися, (*малоупотр.*) ти́ка́тися, тикну́тися кого́, чого́ *и* до ко́го, до чо́го.
>
> *Акаде́мія в усі́х спра́вах, що торка́ються нау́к та осві́ти, ма́є пра́во безпосере́дньо зно́ситися з усіма́ устано́вами* (Ст. А. Н.). *Мовчи́ть, нена́че до йо́го й не стосу́ється* (Сквирщ.). Тут єсть щось таке́, що торка́ється (ти́читься) тебе́ (Звин.).

Подїбна річ з відомим, але совʼєтським і академічно, глузливо названим, тлумачним словником:

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах. — Том 9, 1978. — Стор. 740.](http://sum.in.ua/s/stosuvatysja)

> **СТОСУВАТИСЯ**, **ується**, *недок.*, кого, чого, до кого — чого. Мати відношення до кого-, чого-небудь, бути повʼязаним із кимсь, чимсь.
>
> *Писар напише нам розписку, а я вам заплачу по тій розписці гроші, — сказав Мотуз, дуже обережний, коли діло стосувалось до грошей* (Нечуй-Левицький, IV, 1956, 200); *Дарка вирішила уникати інтимних розмов з Ориською, кого б вони не стосувалися* (Ірина Вільде, Повнолітні діти, 1960, 292); *Щорс швидко пробіг очима пункти наказу, які не стосувалися безпосередньо його полку* (Олександр Довженко, I, 1958, 143); *Богдан стояв осторонь і робив вигляд, ніби його зовсім не стосується вся гра* (Юрій Яновський, II, 1958, 117). *Що стосується кого, чого, до кого — чого, то... — якщо йдеться про когось, щось, то… А що стосується оунівських мучителів, то народ теж не забуває про них* (Юрій Мельничук, Коли кров.., 1960, 95).

---

Отже, проблема через приьменника **до**.

Шкода, що вірних шанувальників або стратили в минулому столїттї, або наразї маьже нїяк не впливають на сучасну мову, хіба що своїми мереживими денниками.

Ось як розрізняє [Олекса Синявськиь](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%9E%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

Норми української літературної мови

[§ 170. Прості прийменники: значіння їх і вживання](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/prosti_pryimennyky)

> 5. до — як прийменник від, дуже поширений в мові, але він з протилежним до від основним значінням: *піти від кого до кого*, *підійти до лісу*, *доскочити до чого* (ширше, загальніше значіння з „*доскочити чого*“), *бути до якого часу*, *ходи до хати, до ніг припасти*, *пити до кого*, *до рук дати*, *говорити до кого*, *узятися до роботи*, *до науки*, *до зброї* і т. ін., також при іменниках, прикметниках: *машина до шиття*, *лист до брата*, *любий до розмови*, *ласий до меду* тощо. Дуже часто конструкції з до чергуються з іншими як рівнобіжними: *рівняти до чого* і *з чим*, п*оздоровкатися до кого* і *з ким*, [*піти до школи* і *в школу*](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/271/585) і т. ін. Надзвичайно часто вживається цей прийменник у виразах прислівникового характеру, хоч і далеко не завсіди пишеться разом (див. § 92), напр.: *до біса*, *до ката*, *до лиха*, *до хріна* (= *багато*), *розказати до крихти* (= *все*), *зробити до діла*, *до пуття* (= *добре*), *сказати до речі* (= *добре*), *бути до вподоби*, *до пари*, *до любови* і т. ін. Див. іще § 144.

[§ 144](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/synaksa_proste_rechennia)

> Дуже багато в мові конструкцій рівнобіжних, але насправді не рівнозначних. Про такі конструкції, надто ж коли вони стосуються до цілих рядів словосполучень, не раз іще буде мова в наступних §§, а тут треба тільки підкреслити вагу й потребу розрізняти, де можна, значіння таких конструкцій, щоб уміти якнайповніше використовувати синтаксичні можливості і не збідняти своєї мови безпідставним обминанням одних конструкцій і пристрастю до других. При дієсловах особливо часто бувають такі подвійні конструкції з різним значінням, надто ж на вираз конкретніших чи виразніших і абстрактніших чи дальших стосунків. Ось кілька прикладів.
>
> При дієслові *належати*, м. ін., можливі дві конструкції: з давальним та родовим з прийменником ‚до‘ *належить мені* і *належить до мене*. Але це різнозначні конструкції, бо перша визначає належність у тісному і здебільшого матеріяльному значінні, друга ж указує на відношення тільки:
>
> > *Увесь край належав Вишневецьким.* (О. Сторож.)
> >     *Ви тепер належите до дому де Мендозів.* (Л. Україн.)
> >     *То до мене не належить.* (Б. Грінч.)
>
> Отож належати кому може книжка, слово, думка ("чиє" воно?), а належати до когось або чогось може хтось або щось в іншому значінні, а саме, заховуючи свою самостійність, тільки стосуватись, торкатись, відноситись, напр., справа належить до такої то установи, належати до партії тощо.
>
> Можна сказати: Цей твір належить такому то письменникові, але він до поезії не належить.
>
> Певна річ, можуть бути й такі випадки, коли й обидві конструкції можливі, напр., *будинок належить житлокопові* і *будинок належить до житлокопа*, хоч і тут добрий знавець мови впіймає різні відтінки значіння, але в жадному разі не може будинок „належати до Іваненка“, а тільки „Іваненкові“.

Відси можна зробити висновки, що коли стосується саме чогось чи прямо, то бажано писати без *до*, але до чогось уявного, не прямо чи невтральнїше — вживати *до*.